# connection refuse error while working with elasticsearch using nodejs

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I am working on elasticsearch using nodejs, here below is my implementation

```
 var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
  host: 'localhost:9200',
  log: 'trace',
  requestTimeout: Infinity, // Tested
  keepAlive: true // Tested
});

    client.ping({
  // ping usually has a 3000ms timeout
  requestTimeout: Infinity,
  // undocumented params are appended to the query string
  hello: "elasticsearch!"
}, function (error) {
  if (error) {
    console.trace('elasticsearch cluster is down!');
  } else {
    console.log('All is well');
  }
});
```

and when i am running this on terminal i am getting this error

```
Error: Request error, retrying
  HEAD http://localhost:9200/?hello=elasticsearch! => connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9200
Trace: elasticsearch cluster is down!Error: No Living connections
```

i have tried every possible way to solve this on Internet but unable to resole this issue, please help

I tried this solution also -> After running elasticsearch server, run the node server but still getting this error(as elasticsearch server running on 9300)

```
Error: Request error, retrying
  HEAD http://localhost:9300/?hello=elasticsearch! => Parse Error
Error: Request error, retrying
HEAD http://localhost:9300/?hello=elasticsearch! => Parse Error
```

As server of elasticsearch is working fine on localhost, here is my curl command on terminal and result

```
curl -X "localhost:9200/customer/_doc?pretty"curl -X POST "localhost:9200/customer/_doc?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
> {
>   "name": "Jane Doe"
> }
> '
{
  "_index" : "customer",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "nywQlmMBz1ZMUBDdRy2R",
  "_version" : 1,
  "result" : "created",
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "successful" : 2,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "_seq_no" : 0,
  "_primary_term" : 1
}
```

Comment: Everything possible? You did actually install and are running your elastic search "server" are you not? And you have actually confirmed you can access that server outside of your program, have you not? Because I see nothing here that actually confirms either of those. Therefore we generally conclude you did not actually install the server and just thought the `npm install` did everything for you. But if you have proof otherwise, then I suggest you actually show it.

Comment: hey thanks for reply, server is installed and it is working fine on localhost:9200 like i am performing curl commands without any issue but when i am trying above, it is not working, please help

Comment: You need to show that "in your question" is the point. A question here needs to be presented in a way in which others can verify and reproduce. We don't sit at your desk, so enough information needs to be here in order to see the actual problem. Show you have a running server and hitting it with something external like `curl` or whatever. Please "no screenshots". Show us how you are actually running the server and state whether your program is attempting to run on the same machine as the server or somewhere else. ECONNREFUSED means your program does not see the server.

Comment: thank you again, i edited this part also in my question

Comment: You are accessing by `curl` on port `9200`. Your code is trying to use port `9300`. See the difference? `HEAD http://localhost:9300/?hello=elasticsearch! => Parse Error`. I know you show code with `9200`, but that's not actually what is happening.

Comment: I think it's working now as i am getting this reponse from nodejs    Elasticsearch INFO: 2018-05-25T07:41:22Z
  Adding connection to http://localhost:9200/customer
 But i have a doubt, is it required to run elasticsearch server separately to work using nodejs because we are using elasticsearch client for Node.js and the browser in nodejs file